# Does a query goes through all data when you only select the last N?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a query that select the last 5($new) items from my database.

```
     SELECT OvenRunData.dataId AS id, OvenRunData.data AS data 
     FROM ovenRuns INNER JOIN OvenRunData ON OvenRuns.id = OvenRunData.ovenRunId 
     WHERE OvenRunData.ovenRunId = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM OvenRuns) 
     ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT '$new'
```

I want to execute this query every 5 seconds with an AJAX request so I can update my table.
I know this query select the last 5 records but I want to know if the query runs through all records and then selects the last 5 or does it select only the last 5 without checking all the data?

I'm really worried that I'll have lag.

Comment: The answer depends on the structure of your tables and available indexing. With proper indexing available there should be no full table scans. Give it a try and see for yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two indexes to make it fast enough:

```
create index ix_OvenRuns_id on OvenRuns(id)
create index ix_OvenRunData_ovenRunId  on OvenRunData(ovenRunId)
```

you can even put `OvenRunData.dataId` `OvenRunData.data` into the second one, or create [clustered index](http://www.sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html), however, these indexes definitely avoid full data scan.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the indexes.

In your case, you should have one on `OverRuns(id)`.

More here: http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results/top-n-queries

Answer (score 0):

The `LIMIT` is applied after the `ORDER BY`, and the `ORDER BY` is applied to the entire result-set. So the answer to your question is, yes it must go through all of the records in your result-set determined by your `WHERE` clause before applying the `LIMIT`.